# Javascript validation nightmare

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get my "username" and "password" fields to verify that there is information in them before submitting the form.

What should I need to add to my HTML and to my JavaScript to have them work! If you want to suggest a new JavaScript, please do!

**HTML:**

```
<form action="validateForm.html" id="registrationForm">

    <label for="username" id="usernameLabel">* Username:</label>

    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="Your username" />

    <div id="usernameError" style="display:none"></div>
    <br/><br/>

    <label for="password" id="passwordLabel">* Password:</label>

    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />

    <div id="passwordError" style="display:none"></div>
    <br/><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" id="submit" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
function validateForm()
{
 if(!document.getElementByName("username"))
 {
  alert("Username field is required!");
 }

 if(!document.forms[0].username){
  alert("Username field is required!");
 }

 if(!document.for (var i = username.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  alert("Username field is required!")
 };)

}
```

Comment: In `HTML5` [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) element has `required` attribute.

Comment: You should be using `getElementById()` instead which is rather preferable ...

Comment: That `for` is so _weird_.

Comment: Not trying to be mean, but... wow! I think not a single one of those is right. This might be a SO record

Comment: Also I don't see any event handler attached to your submit button so either you have to use `onsubmit` event on your `form` OR you need to attach an event handler on your submit button

Comment: well anyone of you can make a better JavaScript for me?

Comment: @MustafaA.Zubaide No, you should rather try it yourself or you will never learn

Comment: I understand that, and you're absolutely right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be getting your input by `id` and then validate its value

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="username" />
<input type="password" id="password" />
```

**JS**

```
function validateForm()
{
    if(!document.getElementById("username").value) // true if input value is null, undefined or ""
    {
        alert("Username field is required!");
    }
    else if(!document.getElementById("password").value)
    {
        alert("Username field is required!");
    } 
}
```

(i strongly recommend you to use more attractive ways of giving users feedback than JS alerts)

Answer (score 0):

I think all of those checks are incorrect in some for, let's start with the first one:

```
if(!document.getElementByName("username"))
{
    alert("Username field is required!");
}
```

1. It's `document.getElementsByName()` (notice the plural)
2. The function returns an array of elements, so you'd still need to check for the value of the one you want (probably 0)
3. This is going to be true always as the field exist, you need to check the value in the input, but right now you are just checking the existence of the input.

Next one is similar:

```
if(!document.forms[0].username){
    alert("Username field is required!");
}
```

1. You are checking the existence of the field, not its value
2. This type of selection is not recommended, you should be using a `document.getElementBy...` better.

And finally:

```
if(!document.for (var i = username.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    alert("Username field is required!")
};)
```

It looks like you tried to make a `for` loop but copy-pasted from above and got this mess... not even going to try to understand why the loop.

---

**Recommendations:**

- Use the attribute `id` and read the fields using `document.getElementById()`
- To check if a field has content, check its value: `.value`
- Add an event handler for the form (`onsubmit="validateForm()"`)
- Make the form validator return `false` if one of the fields is incorrect (otherwise the form will be sent even with the incorrect fields)
- Optionally: use the HTML5 `required` attribute.

So the function would look like:

```
function validateForm()
{
    if(document.getElementById("username").value == "")
    {
        alert("Username field is required!");
        return false;
    }

    // check the other fields
    // .....
}
```

Comment: You're right, I made so many mistakes, and I have changed my JavaScript too many times because I can't get to an answer

Comment: Follow the indications at the end of the answer, and you should be fine. It's a matter of practice :)

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! I'll have to make some edits to make it validate in real-time

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the **DOM** by it name means it will returns an `Array` so you need to get it by

```
if(!document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value == ""){
//do ur stuff
}
```

or

```
if(!document.getElementById("username").value == ""){
//do ur stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest something like this instead:

HTML:

```
<form action="validateForm.html" onSubmit="return validateForm(this)">

    <label for="username" name="usernameLabel">* Username:</label>

    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Your username" />

    <div id="usernameError" style="display:none"></div>
    <br/><br/>

    <label for="password" name="passwordLabel">* Password:</label>

    <input type="password" name="password" />

    <div id="passwordError" style="display:none"></div>
    <br/><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
function isEmpty (field) {
    return field.value === "";
}

function validateForm (form) {
    // assume the form to be valid
    var isValid = true;
    // create a variable to store any errors
    var errors = "";
    // check if the username is empty
    if(isEmpty(form.username)) {
        // our assumption is incorrect, the form is invalid
        isValid = false;
        // append the error message to the string
        errors += "Username field is required!\n";
    }
    if (isEmpty(form.password)) {
        isValid = false;
        errors += "Password field is required!\n";  
    }
    // display the errors if the form is invalid
    if (!isValid) {
        alert(errors);
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

This way, you are passing the form directly to the validateForm function and can easily access each field using their name properties. You can then check if they're empty by determining what their value contains.